# Angular: change value on input event

Tags: javascript, angular

I have textarea. I try to restrict width of value to 10 symbols. I am trying to cut value on `input` event.

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="smsMessage" (input)="changeSMSMessage()"></textarea>

changeSMSMessage() {
  this.smsMessage = this.smsMessage.substr(0, 10);
  console.log(this.smsMessage);
}
```

But it doesn't work. I see that value was cut in `changeSMSMessage()` method, but on UI I see not changed value.
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wDR0QF5fDwEw4KLVkAn5?p=preview)

When I changed event from `input` to `keyup`, it starts work properly. All characters after the tenth are deleted.

So, could someone explain why is `input` event doesn't update value in `textarea`?

Comment: what are  the benefits behind doing this ?? You can directly use `maxlength="10"` attribute which will not allow user to type more than 10 symbols

Comment: I have to show popup with message "SMS length is greater that 250". In example i removed that code.

Comment: I think you should try (oninput)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options :

1 - use the `maxlength="10"` tag of the text area :

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="smsMessage" maxlength="10"></textarea>
```

2 - Use a [reactive form control](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) with a [built-in validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) :

3 - Control the input :

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="smsMessage" (change)="changeSMSMessage()"></textarea>


// TS
changeSMSMessage() {
    this.smsMessage = this.smsMessage.length > 10 ? this.smsMessage.substr(0, 10), this.smsMessage;
}
```

Comment: Woops, forgot to change the property binding ! sorry.

Comment: 1)I can't use `maxlength="10"` because i need to show popup with error message. 2) I will read this article. Thanks 3) `(change)` doesn't work. I changed event in Plunker, and it still doesn't cut width of smsMessage.

Comment: Then use `keypress`

Comment: Also, as i said in question, this example is working with `(keup)="changeSMSMessage()"`. But I want to understand why is it don't work with `(input)` event.

Comment: `keypress` doesn't work because it addes pressed symbol after execution `changeSMSMessage()`. And in the end i have 11 symbols instead of 10

Comment: Go through this blog you might sort out what you are trying to get https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3089-learning-about-the-input-event-from-angular-2.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use formControl and subscribe to it's valueChanges when your component is initialized, which will allow you to use rxjs operators for advanced requirements like performing http requests, apply a debounce until user finish writing a sentence, take last value and omit previous.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-selector',
  template: `
    <input type="text" [formControl]="searchControl" placeholder="search">
  `
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  private searchControl: FormControl;
  private debounce: number = 400;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchControl = new FormControl('');
    this.searchControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(this.debounce), distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe(query => {
        console.log(query);
      });
  }
}
```