# How to extract the input text from angular form using Python Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, angular, selenium

I have already tried .text and get_attribute('value') to get the value from an angular input.

Here's the element,

```
<input class="form-control m-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" name="contact" pattern="^((0091)|(\+91)|0?)[789]{1}\d{9}$" placeholder="Enter contact number" required="" type="text">
```

The screenshot of the element,

[image]

There's an email in this input field. I.g. something.mail.com which I want to get.

Here's the code I have tried,

```
contact = contact_field.get_property("value")
contact = contact_field.get_attribute("value")
contact = contact_field.text
```

Comment: Please share all your code and the HTML of the page you are working on, not the picture

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML:

```
<input class="form-control m-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" name="contact" pattern="^((0091)|(\+91)|0?)[789]{1}\d{9}$" placeholder="Enter contact number" required="" type="text">
```

none of the attibutes caters to the value change within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) on sending text to the `<input>` element.

---

### Deep Dive

The change in the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) occurs incase the *`<input>`* element contains the following attributes and evenets:

- [*change event*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event): The `change` event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when an alteration to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the *`<input>`* event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value. Examples:

  - example#a:

    ```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">
    ```
  - example#b:

    ```
    <input type="text" [ngModel]="mymodel" (ngModelChange)="valuechange($event)" />
    ```
  - example#c:

    ```
    <input type="text" [ngModel]="mymodel" (keypress)="mymodel=$event.target.value"/>
    ```
  - example#d:

    ```
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="smsMessage" (change)="changeSMSMessage()"></textarea>
    ```

**Note**: The HTML specification lists the [*`<input>`* types that should fire the change event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#concept-input-apply).

---

### Example

As an example, for some elements, including `<input type="text">`, the change event doesn't fire until the control loses focus. On entering something into the field below, and then click somewhere else to trigger the event.

HTML:

```
<input placeholder="Enter some text" name="name"/>
<p id="log"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const log = document.getElementById('log');

input.addEventListener('change', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  log.textContent = e.target.value;
}
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Angular 2 change event on every keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359358/angular-2-change-event-on-every-keypress)
- [Angular: change value on input event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965696/angular-change-value-on-input-event)